# How can I remove dead skin from my back?

Tags: personal-care

I've been under the sun for too long. My back starts peeling badly. I can rub the skin off slowly but is there a faster way to do it? I tried wet towel but that seems too slow and not so effective for me. Is ther any alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I consider this scenario similar to the lips dead skin, if we remove dead skin then after certain period of time it will appear again.

Don't try to remove dead skin, If you try to pull dead skin your normal skin will also get pulled out. Better apply some moisturize it will help you to get rid from the dead skin irritation and let your dead skin remove automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The sun is actually killing your skin cells. You should stay out of the sun or wear sunblock. This may prematurely age your skin and you are at risk for more cancers.

Your really don't need to remove the dead skin, as it will flake off by itself. A moisturizing lotion will help if it itches. Use a moisturizer that contains aloe vera or soy to help soothe sunburned skin. Lotions that have something called aloe vera in them help make your skin feel better. Be careful not to use lotions or creams that have any of these things listed in the ingredients: petroleum, benzocaine, or lidocaine.

There are soft bristled, long-handled back-scrubbing brushes you use in the bath / shower (you see them in older TV/movie media).